# Plot a table from selected rows in DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Institution':['Uni1', 'Uni2', 'Uni3', 'Uni1', 'Uni2', 'Uni3'],
                   'Year': [2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019],
                   'Value': [1000000, 2000000, 250000, 2300000, 3000000, 90000],
                   'Rank': [10, 9, 1, 8, 7, 3]})
```

I want to plot the data grouped as a table:

```
       Uni1    Uni2   Uni3
2018 1000000 2000000 250000
2019 2300000 3000000 90000
```

So far, I am just trying to plot a simple table that does not separate by year, and that it looks like:

```
  Uni1    Uni2   Uni3    Uni1    Uni2   Uni3
1000000 2000000 250000 2300000 3000000 90000
```

This is what I'm using:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.table(cellText = df.values.T)
```

That works and prints the whole dataframe, but when I try to get just one row, I get the following:

```
plt.table(cellText = df['Value'].values.T)

TypeError: object of type 'numpy.int64' has no len()
```

I know a solution would be defining a new DataFrame that's only comprised by the row I want plotted, but I doubt that's the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To plot Values column:

```
plt.table(cellText = df[['Value']].values.T)
```

keep in mind that `df[['Value']]` return a DataFrame but `df['Value']` return a Series.

creating rows for each year using [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table):

```
df_table=df.pivot_table(index='Year',columns='Institution',values='Value')
print(df_table)
```

---

```
Institution     Uni1     Uni2    Uni3
Year                                 
2018         1000000  2000000  250000
2019         2300000  3000000   90000
```

then use `plt.table`:

```
plt.table(cellText = df_table.values)
```

Comment: This is great and I'm accepting it as the answer.
Do you know how to plot it as a table but the values with a format of money, i.e. 200000 as $200,000?

Comment: Thanks!. Something like this: `df_table=df.pivot_table(index='Year',columns='Institution',values='Value').astype('str')+'$'`